# Calculating indices by Multiple polygons

Tags: qgis, raster, remote-sensing, raster-calculator

Is there a way in QGIS to perform band math within each area defined by different polygons without clipping the rasters and performing calculations on each one?

I have a vector layer with several neighbourhoods and I would like to calculate a number of different indices for each area for several different image.

I am hoping for a tool like zonal statistics, but rather than getting things like min/max pixel values in each region I would like to calculate things like NDVI.

Comment: When you calculate an indice, e.g., NDVI, you are calculating a value for a pixel (operating between different bands, in that case). How do you want to calculate an indice for a polygon? I think, calculate the indice for each pixel, then the zonal statistic for the polygon. Maybe I am misunderstanding your question. Can you improve it being more specific?